# vuejs router-link blocks the bootstrap 4 modal in Firefox and IE

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I have a page devices.vue where have a button to add a new device using the bootstrap 4 modal. 
This is the button that calls the modal, with is the component

```
<li class="nav-item active ">
  <a class="nav-link g-color eda-button-new" 
    data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#exampleModalLong" 
    <i class="icon-ede-plus nav-new-event-btn"></i> 
    New Device
  </a>
  <app-new-device></app-new-device>
</li>
```

In the same page devices.vue I have the list with all the devices and on each device I have a router-link to be edited.

```
<div class="edit-icon">
    <router-link :to="'/device/edit-device/' + device.rid">
        <a class="nav-link" 
            data-toggle="modal" 
            data-target="#exampleEditModalLong">
            <i class="ti-pencil-alt" 
                aria-hidden="true" 
                data-toggle="tooltip" 
                data-placement="top" 
                title="Edit Token">
            </i>
        </a>
    </router-link>
    <app-edit-device></app-edit-device>
 </div>
```

The problem is the the "a" wrapped with router-link is blocking the edit modal to open. On create a new device I don't use router-link, but when I call the modal with the device info to be edited I have to use router-link to pass the `device.rid`.

If I take delete the router-link, the edit modal works fine, but with it on, in Firefox,IE the modal doesn't show.

Does anyone know what is happening, or how to make it to work? Why in Chrome works fine but in Firefox and IE the router is blocking the modal?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 4 with jQuery?

Comment: Yes, because without jquery library will not work some bootstrap components, and this modal is one of them.

Comment: Try use Vue-Bootstrap (Bootstrap port without jQuery) and see if your app with that plugin won't cause any conflicts